# What is the difference between こんにちは and もしもし?

Tags: definitions, word-choice, learning

I will be in Japan in a few weeks and I am trying to learn the basic to be as polite as possible.

One of the first things I did was try some basic stuff with Google Translate but I feel lost already.

When I try to translate `hello` from english to japanese I get: [`こんにちは`](http://translate.google.com/#en/ja/hello)

When I try `Hello` I get: [`もしもし`](http://translate.google.com/#en/ja/Hello)

Why is there a difference, is this a Google issue or there is a real difference between both?
Which one should I use to say: **Hello**

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jordan and welcome to JLU. There is clearly a difference between the two, and explaining it could make a valid (albeit extremely basic) question. However, the way your question is currently phrased, **your question is asking about an external software tool, not Japanese** and it therefore off-topic for JLU. Please edit your question accordingly. Moreover, I hope you do realise that Google Translate is nowhere near accurate enough to provide you useful help in learning even basic Japanese.

Comment: @Dave The body of the question is about Japanese and not an external software tool.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to rephrase, but as @user1205935 said, the main question was what is the difference between こんにちは and もしもし. 
UPDATE: snailplane did the rephrase. Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to second the idea that you shouldn't try to learn Japanese from Google Translate.  Please see the question [Resources for learning Japanese](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese).

Comment: Thanks @snailplane you all are right, I just wanted to get a glimpse at it and when I found out that Hello and hello was different I was(am) a little bit scared of trying to learn it. Buy I will give it a try.I love trying to speak the main language of the places I travel to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

こんにちは is "Hello!" or "Good day!", a greeting for meeting someone in any sort of circumstance.

もしもし is how you answer a phone. Usually both parties say もしもし in turn, before the caller identifies himself ("Hi, it's John"). Outside phone conversations, it is also used to get someone's attention, but I feel it is quite direct, more like "Hey!". (To get someone's attention, the better alternative would be to clear your throat, say え～っと, or すみません, or any combination of these three options.)

To summarize, use こんにちは when you mean "Hello!" and もしもし only when answering the phone.

Comment: For もしもし, it need not be a phone. It is usable when calling out to someone (usually a stranger) around you.

Comment: I don't think こんにちは is appropriate in any circumstance; for instance, night, or very early in the morning.

Comment: もしもし is also used on intercoms, door phones, and the like